# How to check current mouse position beyond my view area

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, mouseevent, controls

I have found the following open source that is easy example about dragging and dropping controls in WPF.
"http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/148503/Simple-Drag-Selection-in-WPF"
With this source, I met the problems that when I move control, this moved control can move to outside of view area and disappear from this view.
Until now, I'm still stuck in the root. Any one can help me to solve this problem?
Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Any code to show?  This will help us help you.  Good luck!

Comment: Get mouse coordinates and check x/y values are < 0 or,  greater than actualwidth/actualheight of window.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @MickyD. I just code the example like the source code in above link. So, I don't know how to fix this bug :(

Comment: Thank you @AnjumSKhan. I used to try getting mouse coordinates. This method corrects when catching point of mouse in control. But I don't know how to get the point of bound of control. If I can get this point, I will use its to compare with actualwidth/actualheight.

Answer (score 0):

For you control override the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event and inside of this method get the mouse position coordinates relative to a screen.

Right after call the 
CaptureMouse();
for your control.

This will allow you to monitor the mouse move outside of your control, so make sure you override the PreviewMouseMove and inside of the PreviewMouseMove you should be able to make your calculations of whether the mouse is inside or outside of the control’s area or any other areas you want to compare against.

In addition you will need to override the PreviewMouseUp and inside of it release the mouse capture ReleaseMouseCapture();  from the previous PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown call. This is important or you will end up with weirdly behaving mouse.

Comment: Thank for your comment. For your reply, I know what I need to do now :D